# Why u-boot starts so late after I give power

Tags: u-boot, fpga

Running PetaLinux from sd card on ARM cortex A9 based Zynq zc702 board. Zynq is an SoC with ARM and FPGA.

Before the log messages (corresponding to U-Boot) starts printing, the screen (serial console) is blank, but power is already given.

So there is considerable time delay (actually around 10 seconds) between the point I give power and the u-boot log messages come on the screen.

1. What is happening during this time?
2. How to minimize this time?
3. How to print log messages of this duration?

My U-Boot is in `BOOT.BIN` file, which has three components:

1. First Stage Boot loader (FSBL)
2. `download.bit` (FPGA configuration file)
3. U-Boot

I have noticed that if I skip `download.bit` file, the resulting `BOOT.BIN` `file is 500k. But If I keep`download.bit`file the resulting`BOOT.BIN` file is 4.2 MB.

Is this  (i.e `download.bit`) the reason of delay?

**Log messages**

```
Power was give at approximately 14:32 and you can see u-boot is starting after 10 seconds. 

[Tue Apr 08 14:42:30.650 2014] 
[Tue Apr 08 14:42:30.650 2014] 
[Tue Apr 08 14:42:30.650 2014] U-Boot 2013.07 (Apr 07 2014 - 13:23:59)
[Tue Apr 08 14:42:30.650 2014] 
[Tue Apr 08 14:42:30.650 2014] Memory: ECC disabled
[Tue Apr 08 14:42:30.650 2014] DRAM:  1 GiB
[Tue Apr 08 14:42:30.662 2014] SF: Detected N25Q128A with page size 64 KiB, total 16 MiB
[Tue Apr 08 14:42:30.683 2014] In:    serial
[Tue Apr 08 14:42:30.683 2014] Out:   serial
[Tue Apr 08 14:42:30.683 2014] Err:   serial
```

Comment: Isn't that obvious?

Comment: but even when I removed doonload.bit, the same situation

Comment: Well, this is not a CPU, it is an FPGA, the FPGA needs to download the data from a source before getting the internal CPU to load the Linux boot loader. That takes time. Depending on the type and size of your FPGA, it can take some time for the FPGA to load it's configuration.